# Any way to be notified of activity on your Favorites?

Tags: support, bookmarks

It used to be that if there was activity on a question you marked as a Favorite, the little envelope icon would light up to let you know. The little envelope is gone now, so is there another way to be informed about activity on Favorites?

Answer (score 6):

They are now listed in your profile dropdown.

[image: More awesome - favourites]

There are no inbox notifications though - you just have to check the drop down.

Comment: How embarrassing, I forgot my free hand awesome-ness. Don't tell anyone will you.

Comment: What freehand awesomeness? You can't even draw a complete circle!

Comment: @BoltClock: That part is transparent so I didn't ruin the view of the tooltip ;-D

Comment: The main problem with this is: if it's a _comment_ on one of your favorite questions, it's very hard to find out which question it is.