# get notified on any activity on a particular question?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

**EDIT: Summary**

I think I've found the best definition of what I want thanks to the discussion with @M. Tibbits:

When I open or refresh the SO, I get a notification of new activities that are of interest to me. Today these are (hard-coded): answers to my questions and comments addressed to me. I want a bit more control over it, that's all.

---

Yes, I've read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/how-can-i-watch-a-question-in-stack-overflow) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95518/any-way-to-be-notified-of-activity-on-your-favorites), but I think I add new (good :) ) reasons for re-asking it:

The first question was answered **before** this so handy "inbox" notification feature was implemented. So now using favorites for "watching" a question is wrong, IMHO, for 2 reasons:

- it **splits** essentially the **same functionality** (of `getting notified when there is an activity you are interested in`) between 2 very different user interfaces
- it's **cumbersome** - I need to: 1) add question to favorites; 2) click on my profile dropdown; 3) click on the "favorites" line; 4) see all my favorites with recent activity; 5) select the one I watch; 6) repeat this process occasionally to get updates; and 7) possibly remove the question from favorites at the end. All this as opposed to this little red button when there are news.

Favorites are **different in nature** that watching. I add a question to Favorites when I find the **answers** useful to me in my work, so I may want to have it handy in the future. By watching an interesting question I will be able to decide **whether** I want it in faviorites, **after** I see the answers.

**EDIT**: I see that I was not clear enough.

I want to add a question to Favorites when:

1. it has some **good** answers
2. the question **and answers** are relevant in my work
3. I want to keep them handy as my long-term (persistent) knowledge base

I want to watch a question for short while (matter of days/weeks) when:

1. it is interesting / relevant
2. I want to follow it to see what are the answers. Then I can decide whether I want it in my favorites

As you see, the main differentiators are good answers and long/short term. For short-term, automatic notification is better.

Bottom line, all I ask is "watch this question" checkbox (which may expire after say a week if there is a need to free resources)

Comment: So you already found the star? I don't understand what you're asking for here. Why in the world do we need "interesting questions" *and* "favorites"? I don't even know what the difference is.

Comment: So you [want to favorite answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star) (instead of questions)?

Comment: @Cody: I tried to explain, obviously not so well, I'll have another take by editing the question

Comment: @M. Tibbits, no, I just want to watch the question for a while as it's the **good answers** that make me add it to favorites.

Comment: And by that you mean the RSS question feed?

Comment: @M. Tibbits: no, I don't want a 3rd tool as a solution for not wanting to have 2, thank you :) Let's return to the beginning for a moment, ok? When I open or refresh the SO, I get a notification of new activities that are of interest to me. Today these are (hard-coded): answers to my questions and comments addressed to me. I want a bit more control over it, that's all.

Comment: Ahh.  Sorry for the confusion.