# What does the "favorites" statistic reflect in the user info drop down?

Tags: support

When you mouseover your username, there's the personal statistics like reputation, votes, revisions, and favorites.

What does *favorites* reflect??  It doesn't seem like it is the question favorites that I favorite.  What does that number mean?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95519/148158

Comment: And how many people just favorited and un-favorited this post just to test it?

Comment: @hammar Genius!!  I see it's the activity on posts you've favorited.  Please post that as the answer and I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hover over the number, you will see that it shows the activity on questions you've favorited.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That is one of the things I love the most about StackExchange sites.  Tooltip all the things!